# SSL Security Error for some mobile users

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I moved my website [arvandkala.ir](https://arvandkala.ir) to `https` recently.
The problem is that some user (specially on mobile) get `SSL pravicy Error`
the user mobile clock is ok,
don't have a any mixing data on website.
firefox error code:

```
SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

the issuer is Certum and trusted by firefox.

[image]
[image]

Comment: See https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=arvandkala.ir where it says 'Certificate chain is incomplete' and click to expand under 'Certification paths'. Some browsers can fetch the missing cert themselves using AIA but some can't. PS: a clock error would show up as 'expired' or possibly 'invalid' but never 'unknown'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for comment, i see chain is incomplete , but how to solve that. i test several way but not solved yet.please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: it's the chain cert**

You need to get the correct chain cert from the CA and configure it in your server.

Normally a CA provides the correct chain cert (or sometimes certs plural) when you buy or obtain your server cert, and also makes all its chain certs (usually several) available on its website, but since I don't know Polish and don't know any customers of your CA `certum.pl` I can't address these approaches here. Nowadays a common alternative is for the cert itself to specify a way to obtain its parent cert, in the `caIssuers` attribute in the `AuthorityInfoAccess` extension. This can be seen with many tools, including (at least) desktop browsers, OpenSSL (`x509 -noout -text -in $file`), and Java keytool (`-printcert -v -file $file`), and your cert does have it, pointing to `http://repository.certum.pl/dvcasha2.cer` . Fetching that URL with a tool that does not interpret the content (i.e. not a browser, but things like curl wget perl python or javascript) does yield the correct cert, in DER format.

Configuring your server varies hugely depending on the server, which you didn't identify. Your server identifies in a response as `Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)` but this could be falsified because some people consider that a good way to confuse attackers (not very) or mistaken because some other terminator is in front. If true, although there are other possibilities I'll assume the common default `mod_ssl`. The [documentation for Apache 2.4 mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html) is located on the Apache website under docs / 2.4 / modules / mod_ssl . As this page tells you for 2.4.8 up you can include the PEM-format chain cert with the server cert in the file specified by `SSLCertificateFile`, but below that you must put them both in a file specified by `SSLCertificateChainFile` instead. This config (certificate including chain, plus privatekey) can be per virtualhost, or if you don't need them to be different it can be global. On Ubuntu the usual practice (though not mandatory) is to put each virtualhost config in a separate file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and link it under `(same)/sites-enabled`.

Since the certficate obtained from the CA was in DER format you must first convert it to PEM format. This can be done directly by OpenSSL with `openssl x509 -inform der -in $derfile -out $pemfile` or by numerous other programs that can import DER format and then write out PEM format (including at least Windows, Firefox/NSS, and Java).